# Selecting columns based on time ranges

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, time-series-database

I have a table which looks like this:

```
Table t1

timestamp (pkey)     | A  | B | C
----------------------------------
2024-01-01 12:00:00  | 1  | 2 | 2
2024-01-01 12:00:01  | 1  | 2 | 2
2024-01-01 12:00:03  | 15 | 4 | 2
```

Table creation SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 ("id" serial NOT NULL, "timestamp" timestamp PRIMARY KEY, "A" real, "B" real, "C" real)
```

Some tables might have 100+ columns.

I'd like to select several columns having omitting time ranges on per column basis. The way I do it today is like the following:

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN timestamp NOT BETWEEN '2017-06-12T17:01' AND '2018-06-12T21:57'
                    AND timestamp NOT BETWEEN '2020-06-12T17:01' AND '2021-02-15T21:57' THEN A ELSE NULL END) "A",

(CASE WHEN timestamp NOT BETWEEN '2018-07-14' AND '2019-01-01'
                    AND timestamp NOT BETWEEN '2020-06-12T17:01' AND '2021-02-15T21:57' THEN B ELSE NULL END) "B",

C
FROM t1
WHERE timestamp > '2014-01-01'
```

`timestamp` is an index obviously.

Is there a better / more effective way to do it?

Comment: no, but what says EXPLAIN and ANALAYSE

Comment: Sounds like you need to normalize your table into rows.

Comment: The index will help with the `WHERE` condition, but it cannot help with the `CASE`, nor is there a need to speed up the `CASE`. This smells as if there could be a better data model.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please show us the DDL for the table concerned - you can give us a shortened version - as per your example above. Also, as an aside, it is **not** a good idea to use SQL and/or PostgreSQL keywords as identifiers - i.e. column, table, index... whatever names. See the list [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words) for identifiers to be avoided - it makes debugging difficult and your system less portable.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I was suggested many times to change the data model. But think of it this way - I sometimes have 600 columns of data, with millions of rows. The data is usually aligned to timestamps.  Putting all the data in TIMESTAMP-NAME-VALUE structure (which is usually the recommendation) has a horrible performance when you need to select multiple columns or JOIN it with other similarly structured  tables.

Comment: Is the same time range repeated for many columns, or does every column get a separate range? Please disclose the exact, minimal table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) and your version of Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter it was just an example - every columns get a separate (bad) ranges in addition to global range. Postgres 15. CREATE TABLE updated in question.

Answer (score 0):

[Don't use `BETWEEN` for timestamps.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29)
I also inverted the logic in the `CASE` expression to simplify, and to not exclude values for `timestamp IS NULL` (which may or may not be allowed).

```
SELECT CASE WHEN timestamp >= '2017-06-12T17:01' AND timestamp < '2018-06-12T21:58'
              OR timestamp >= '2020-06-12T17:01' AND timestamp < '2021-02-15T21:58' THEN null ELSE a END AS a
     , CASE WHEN timestamp >= '2018-07-14'       AND timestamp < '2019-01-02'
              OR timestamp >= '2020-06-12T17:01' AND timestamp < '2021-02-15T21:58' THEN null ELSE b END AS b
     , c
FROM   t1
WHERE  timestamp > '2014-01-01';
```

We don't *need* parentheses. [Operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) works in our favor in either query.

Comment: that's an interesting observation. But will it improve the performance also?

Comment: @Miro: Barely. The `CASE` expressions cost close to nothing. The `WHERE` clause drives the cost. Looks like you are selecting *many* rows.